# How to set alarm every 3rd months till end date from start date Android Notification Manger

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, alarm, notificationmanager

I searched everywhere but I didn't get any correct code for my problem.

I wanted to set alarm for every 3rd month starting from a start date till end date. Where start date and end date are as string like "14/03/2016".

This is what I did till now:

```
AlarmManager am;

public void createNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowAllAccounts.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);

    // Build notification
    // Actions are just fake
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Your interest " + ""+interstamount)
        .setContentText("Your interest is due today").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.timelogo)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.icon1, "Yes", pendingIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.icon2, "No", pendingIntent).build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
}
```

ie. User inputs a date say 14/03/2016 and period is 12 months. then I want to show notification on 14/6/2016 then +3 months 14/9/2016 then +3 14/12/2016 and at last on 14/3/2017. What changes I have to do?

Comment: Where is your problem? Do you know how to parse date objects?

Comment: i dont know where to specify start date and end date and repeat every 3rd month here...

Comment: it does'nt repeating